# Publish MVC 4 in IIS 7 connecting to MySQL Database using FullCalendar

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, entity-framework-4, fullcalendar

Good day!!

im having trouble connecting to the database after publishing the project to the IIS 7
my local pc

it runs in windows authentication which works just fine... but after the authentication

the fullcalendar displays but it didn't connect to the database unlike when its on VS 2012 Prof.

it works fine.. but when i publish it using File System.. it just displays the fullcalendar and no connecting to the database

here is link of the sample of my project with its database MySql

btw. am using entity framework 4.4 mysql 6.6.5

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7vFDG3kiOeCenpqdTFlOEFPajg/edit?usp=sharing

thank you in advance to help

Comment: are you getting any errors? logs? anything that would indicate what the problem may be?

Comment: hmm actually when the page was loaded... it just displays the fullcalendar and it doesn't connect to the database

i try to send the connection state of the database in entity framework  to viewbag.title

and it says closed

have you check the sample of the .sln project of mine.. ive posted the link here...

hope that helps..